# replace a string in a csv file with powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

I need to place System.Object[] for some columns in a csv file. I tried 3 different method but none of them are working. System.Object[] is put in by powershell when that object is empty or something.

```
$file = "c:\output.csv"

(gc $file) -replace "'system.object[]'", ""
[io.file]::readalltext($file).replace("'system.object[]'","")
(Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "system.object[]", "" } ) | Set-Content $file
```

Comment: don't understand you need to add or remove the System.Object[] text?

Comment: Remove it because users are getting confused with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added following code to the variable that containing System.Object[] on output.  and it's seems to be working. and now I dont have to do the replacement at file level.

```
"Access Code" = (@($AccessCode) | Out-String).Trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

The bracers and the dot ([, ], .) need all to be escaped. Furthermore remove the double quotation marks, just keep the single ones. Also think about using creplace, in case you want to work case insensitive. So the command would look like this:

```
(gc $file) -replace 'system\.object\[\]', ''
```

In case you want to write everything to a new file:

```
(gc $file) -replace 'system\.object\[\]', ''|out-file "test2.txt" -encoding ASCII
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Escape character

```
(gc $file) -replace 'system.object\[\]', ""
```

> The characters '[' and ']' are used for Regex pattern. You must use Escape
>   character '\' to tell Powershell that This is a regular chars

Comment: Thanks for the code. I think I solved the problem. but will try yours as well. Thanks again.